# Ancestry, has_many_roots?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-loops

I'm new to ruby on rails, and I need to make a Post/Comment relationship, with nested comments, like authors can reply to each other.

Made it like this:

post/comments.html:

```
<% @post.comments.roots.each do |c| %>
  <%= nested_messages c.subtree.arrange(:order => :created_at) %>
<% end %>
```

This works pretty well, but obviously needs a lot of queries to render a tree, like *N+1*, where *N* is `comments.root.count`.

Thanks for help!

**UPD:** 
Soluton with .includes() didn't work for my case, but I'm not 100% sure I was doing all things correctly...

The solution worked for me was pretty obvious - to arrange Comments themself, by specifying post_id:

```
<%= nested_messages Comment.where('post_id = ?', @post.id).arrange(:order => :created_at) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `include` to eager load your associations, this prevents N+1 queries.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-multiple-associations

Answer (score 0):

You can optimize N+1 problem by using `includes` method

Hope this works for your code

```
@post.comments.roots.includes(:subtree)
```

I could not help with `arrange` because you didnt specify the version you are dealing with

Answer (score 0):

If your tree structure look like this:

```
Post
  comment (root1)
    comment (child11)
    comment (child12)
  comment(root2)
    comment (child21)
    comment (child22)
 ... and so on
```

May be better to remodel structure to this:

```
Post
  comment (meta root, only one, which holder other comments 'roots' and we never render this comment in the view)
    comment (child1)
      comment (child11
    comment (child2)
      comment (child21)
    comment (child3)
    ... and so on
```

And now will be executed 2 (or 3?) queries instead of N+1

Answer (score 0):

Soluton with .includes() didn't work for my case, but I'm not 100% sure I was doing all things correctly...

The solution worked for me was pretty obvious - to arrange Comments themself, by specifying post_id:

```
<%= nested_messages Comment.where('post_id = ?', @post.id).arrange(:order => :created_at) %>
```